Hbuilderx compilation of uniapp code reported an error. Could you please show me what the problem is?
Syntax Error: ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'data'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }

package.json
{
  "name": "smart-shop-multiPort",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "npm run dev:h5",
    "build": "npm run build:h5",
    "build:app-plus": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=app-plus vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:custom": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production uniapp-cli custom",
    "build:h5": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=h5 vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:mp-360": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=mp-360 vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:mp-alipay": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=mp-alipay vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:mp-baidu": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=mp-baidu vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:mp-kuaishou": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=mp-kuaishou vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:mp-qq": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=mp-qq vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:mp-toutiao": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=mp-toutiao vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:mp-weixin": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=mp-weixin vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:quickapp-native": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=quickapp-native vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:quickapp-webview": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=quickapp-webview vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:quickapp-webview-huawei": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=quickapp-webview-huawei vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "build:quickapp-webview-union": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production UNI_PLATFORM=quickapp-webview-union vue-cli-service uni-build",
    "dev:app-plus": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=app-plus vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:custom": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development uniapp-cli custom",
    "dev:h5": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=h5 vue-cli-service uni-serve",
    "dev:mp-360": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=mp-360 vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:mp-alipay": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=mp-alipay vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:mp-baidu": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=mp-baidu vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:mp-kuaishou": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=mp-kuaishou vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:mp-qq": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=mp-qq vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:mp-toutiao": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=mp-toutiao vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:mp-weixin": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=mp-weixin vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:quickapp-native": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=quickapp-native vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:quickapp-webview": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=quickapp-webview vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:quickapp-webview-huawei": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=quickapp-webview-huawei vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "dev:quickapp-webview-union": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development UNI_PLATFORM=quickapp-webview-union vue-cli-service uni-build --watch",
    "info": "node node_modules/@dcloudio/vue-cli-plugin-uni/commands/info.js",
    "serve:quickapp-native": "node node_modules/@dcloudio/uni-quickapp-native/bin/serve.js",
    "test:android": "cross-env UNI_PLATFORM=app-plus UNI_OS_NAME=android jest -i",
    "test:h5": "cross-env UNI_PLATFORM=h5 jest -i",
    "test:ios": "cross-env UNI_PLATFORM=app-plus UNI_OS_NAME=ios jest -i",
    "test:mp-baidu": "cross-env UNI_PLATFORM=mp-baidu jest -i",
    "test:mp-weixin": "cross-env UNI_PLATFORM=mp-weixin jest -i",
    "lint": "eslint --config .eslintrc.js --fix --ext .ts,.vue src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@dcloudio/uni-app-plus": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-cli-i18n": "^2.0.2-4000820240401001",
    "@dcloudio/uni-h5": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-helper-json": "*",
    "@dcloudio/uni-i18n": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-mp-360": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-mp-alipay": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-mp-baidu": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-mp-kuaishou": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-mp-qq": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-mp-toutiao": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-mp-vue": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-mp-weixin": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-quickapp-native": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-quickapp-webview": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-stat": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-ui": "^1.4.9",
    "@vue/shared": "^3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "flyio": "^0.6.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "puppeteer": "^22.6.5",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.12.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-class-component": "^6.3.2",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.0.0",
    "vuex": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-typescript": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "~7.12.0",
    "@dcloudio/types": "*",
    "@dcloudio/uni-automator": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-cli-shared": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-migration": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/uni-template-compiler": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/vue-cli-plugin-hbuilderx": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/vue-cli-plugin-uni": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/vue-cli-plugin-uni-optimize": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/webpack-uni-mp-loader": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@dcloudio/webpack-uni-pages-loader": "^2.0.0-31920210514002",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.170",
    "@types/md5": "^2.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "*",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.11.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "jest": "^25.4.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.0",
    "mini-types": "*",
    "miniprogram-api-typings": "*",
    "node-sass": "^4.0.0",
    "postcss-comment": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss-pxtorpx-pro": "^1.0.0",
    "px2rpx-loader": "^0.1.10",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "Android >= 4",
    "ios >= 8"
  ],
  "uni-app": {
    "scripts": {}
  }
}

How can NPM run build not report errors?
